# saving file from googledrive c++

Tags: c++, api, curl, download, google-drive-api

I need some help.
I am trying to save a standard file from google drive using the console.

Here's the code:

```
 m_pHeadersList = NULL; 
 int NotF; // number of the file
 cout << endl << "choose file to download:"; cin >> NotF;

 access_token = FileLoad ("access_token");
 m_tmpStr = "Authorization: Bearer " + access_token;
 m_pHeadersList = curl_slist_append(m_pHeadersList, m_tmpStr.c_str());

 GETreq(curl, res, ws2s(files[NotF].downloadUrl) , m_pHeadersList);
```

Here's the code of the GETreq function:

```
void GETreq(CURL *curl, CURLcode res, string URL, curl_slist* m_pHeadersList)
{
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_ALL);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST , 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO , "cacert.pem");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, NULL); 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, m_pHeadersList); 

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

    static const char *headerfilename1 = "head1.out";
    FILE *headerfile1;
    static const char *bodyfilename1 = "body1.out";
    FILE *bodyfile1;

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);

    headerfile1 = fopen(headerfilename1,"wb");
    bodyfile1 = fopen(bodyfilename1,"wb");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl,   CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, headerfile1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,   CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, bodyfile1);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    fclose(headerfile1);
    fclose(bodyfile1);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
}
```

It works, but it saves files (txt, xml and even jpg) to the body1.out as text.
I need some advice on how to get files downloaded with their own extension.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dealed with it. Just changed parameter in function

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

to

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```